# Calculating mean percents

Tags: mean

Are there any rules to calculating mean percent or is it the same as calculating any other average (i.e., add all of the percents together and divide by the sample size)?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/which-mean-to-use-and-when

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason why the mean should not be appropriate here. You might want to consider using the median to reduce the influence of outliers, but that is a point not specifically related to percentages.