# Should I use arithmetic or geometric mean here?

Tags: mean, geometric-mean, types-of-averages

So I have monthly indices (Consumer Price Indices for 12 months) for a given country. I want to calculate the annual average for each country in order to have an average Consumer Price Index for a given year, not month.

Do I calculate the annual average by simply summing all 12 monthly data points (i.e. monthly indices) and divide by 12; or should I be using the geometric mean here?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/which-mean-to-use-and-when/23199#23199