# Learning Statistics

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, mean

I am new to statistics and I am trying to get my head around 'why' some of these are calculated the way they are and what they mean, or were they just made a preference that stuck? - the statistics books I'm using don't seem to frame things and provide context:

Variance:  why square the values

Standard Deviation:  why 68%

Geometric mean:  why is it useful

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because 2 of 3 questiosn are answered elsewhere Re: geometric mean see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/which-mean-to-use-and-when Re: variance see: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118/why-square-the-difference-instead-of-taking-the-absolute-value-in-standard-devia and the remaining one is unclear. `Standard Deviation: why 68%` Could you clarify what this means? 68% of what? How does 68% relate to standard deviation?

Comment: It's pretty obvious that 68% refers to the often stated and used fact that the probability of being within (+ or -) 1 standard deviation of the mean of a Normal random variable is ~68%.  But yes, not the clearest wording in the question.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I was hoping that by writing out an explanation of the question, the asker would improve their understanding of the topic and perhaps answer their own question.

Comment: @C11H17N2O2SNa , yes,Ii thought that might be the case, but in any event, I essentially answered that item, which was the only one not addressed by the links you provided.

Answer (score 2):

I am also new to statistics, but I think I can answer your questions in a basic way.

### Variance

Suppose you have these two datasets: $\{10, 20, 30, 40\}$ and $\{24, 25, 26\}$. Both have the arithmetic mean $ \mu = 25 $ but their variance is very different.

You want to know the *average variance* around the mean. To do that, you take the *deviations from the mean* and divide them by the number of items in the data set:

$$ \frac{\sum(x_{i}-\bar{x})}{N} $$

So for the latter example, it would be $ \frac{(24-25)+(26-25)}{3}$. However the answer here would be $ = 0 $ because the positive and the negative deviations neutrilize each other.

So that's why we introduce ***variance*** ($ \sigma^{2} $):

$$ \sigma^{2} = \frac{\sum(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}}{N} $$

By squaring the deviations, we are removing the neutrilizing effect of averaging the deviations.

The ***standard deviation*** is simply the square root of the variance: $ \sigma = \sqrt{\sigma^{2}} $

Another way of doing this would be to use the ***Mean Average Deviation (MAD)*** by converting the deviations to absolute values:

$$ MAD = \frac{\sum\mid{x_{i}-\bar{x} \ \mid}}{N} $$

### Empirical rule

The 68 % you are referring to in regards to the standard deviation is part of what's known as the ***[Empirical rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule)***. Empirical studies have shown that when a distribution is ***normally distributed*** (bell-shaped curve), it is *very* probable that:

- $ 68 \%$ of all values in the distribution are likely to be found within $ \pm1 \sigma $ (1 standard deviation) from the mean $ \mu $.
- $ 95 \%$ of all values in the distribution are likely to be found within $ \pm2 \sigma $ (2 standard deviations) from the mean $ \mu $.
- $ 99.7 \%$ of all values in the distribution are likely to be found within $ \pm3 \sigma $ (3 standard deviations) from the mean $ \mu $.

So if you know the standard deviation (*the average variance*) of a data set, you know that 95 % of all values can be found within the *double range* of the average variance's range.

If the mean is $\mu = 200$ and the standard deviation is $ \sigma = 40 $, then 95 % of the values can be found in the range 120 – 280:

$ -2\sigma < \mu < 2\sigma = -120 < 200 < 280 $

### Geometric mean

Has been answered [elsewhere](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/which-mean-to-use-and-when) as per the comment above, but one reason (not specific to statistics) would be because there has been a compounding of values, where the arithmetic mean would give the wrong impression. See this [link](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/geometricmean.asp) relating to finance for instance.

Comment: Thank you.  It helps me with both the specific, and in understanding better how to participate in this community - fair criticism; Cross Validated is a very well-focused community.  Appreciate the time and effort in being able to infer what I was actually asking -