# Arithmetic and Geometric Means

Tags: arithmetic, geometric-mean

The arithmetic and geometric averages provide a summary of historical performance. They are both unique in calculation and contain biases (as stated by my lecturer).

My question is where exactly are these underlying biases with respect to calculation and under which situation (with example) would a statistician prefer to use the arithmetic average over the geometric and vise versa.

Thank you

Comment: I think your question may well be largely answered at [Which “mean” to use and when?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23117/22228) If that doesn't answer your question, can you edit your question here to emphasise in what way this one differs?

Comment: There's also a Harmonic Mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_means