# Central tendency of survey results and geometric mean

Tags: survey, weighted-mean, geometric-mean

I recently conducted a survey asking users about their music listening habits at different times of day. Here are the results from 6am in the morning:

[image]

Taking a weighted average, 32.14% seems quite high. The Median doesn't work well with only having 6 choices.

Would it be appropriate to use a Geometric mean for a distribution that looks like this?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/23199/7071

Comment: Thanks @dimitriy for the quick and helpful response! In thinking about it, I'm not certain whether this is a level, ratio, or rate. % of time feels like it might be ratio?

Comment: It’s a ratio, since the outcome is minutes/minutes, so the units cancel.